# What is the basis for the Catechism saying that one can always be forgiven by perfect contrition come from?

Tags: catholicism, biblical-basis, forgiveness, catholic-catechism

According to [*CCC* 1452](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P4D.HTM#-1PE):

> 1452 When it arises from a love by which God is loved above all else, contrition is called "perfect" (contrition of charity). Such contrition remits venial sins; it also obtains forgiveness of mortal sins if it includes the firm resolution to have recourse to sacramental confession as soon as possible.<sup>51</sup>
>
> <sup><sup>51</sup> Council of Trent (1551): DS 1677.</sup>

Thus, all sins, venial or mortal, can be forgiven by perfect contrition—that a sinner must sincerely repent and confess, and that's enough for God to forgive all sins, even the ones against Holy Spirit (as long as the sinner shows repentance).

What are, either Biblical, or infallible Catholic, statements, supporting this?

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for contributing. If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is given in footnote 51 of what you quote:

[Fourteenth Session of the Council of Trent (1551), "On the Most Holy Sacraments of Penance and Extreme Unction," ch. 4, "On Contrition"](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/creeds2.v.i.i.vii.html#v.i.i.vii-p8.27):

> The Synod teaches…that…it sometimes happens that this contrition is perfect through charity, and reconciles man with God before this sacrament be actually received…

The Council of Trent is infallible because its documents were ratified by a pope.

Comment: My original post, before the edit, was talking about something different.  The part of CCC you added is saying that perfect contrition remits mortal sins, but doesn't say whether it remits ALL mortal sins.  There is some part of CCC, which I will try to find, that says all sins can be forgiven and will be forgiven by repentance. Fortunately though, a while ago I found an ex cathedra document saying that it's true - DS 349, where pope Gelasius I talks about this.

Comment: Found it. I was talking about CCC982, "There is no one, however wicked and guilty, who may not confidently hope for forgiveness, provided his repentance is honest."

Comment: @Qwedfsf  In case that wasn't clear, ”perfect contrition” _is_ repentance: it is repentance motivated by supernatural love for God (i.e., charity). (There is also something called imperfect contrition, which is repentance motivated by something else, such as fear of the consequences. What sacramental confession does, if the person has only imperfect contrition, is transform that imperfect contrition into perfect contrition.)